# here i got the error .class expected..please tell where is the problem

Tags: java

```
double latitude = double.parseDouble( latlng[0] ); 
longitude = double.parseDouble(latlng[1]);                 
latlng location = new latlng( latitude, longitude );here
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is case sensitive, so be careful about that.

Use

```
Double.parseDouble
```

instead of `double.parseDouble`.

You are trying to use the `parseDouble` method that exists in the `Double` class, but you are using the primitive type `double` which has no methods.

Class names should always begin with an uppercase letter, so whatever the `latlng` class is (that you try to use) should be called LatLng or something similar. I suspect it is one of your own classes?